# Approximation algorithms for NP-complete problems

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, approximation-algorithms

Given two NP NP-hard functional problems, A and B, one can find a reduction of A to B. Is it possible to find a reduction that would honour approximations? That is, if you have an approximation algorithm for B that yield approximate solutions within accuracy $\delta$, is it possible to reduce A to B in such a way that one would be able to derive an approximate solution of A within accuracy $\epsilon = \epsilon(\delta)$?

Comment: I'll leave a proper answer to experts, but let me point you towards the notion of [strong np-completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_NP-complete).

Comment: In certain circumstances an approximation-preserving reduction is possible. These instances are characterized by [L-reductions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-reduction). However, as  @Raphael, noted, not all problems possess this feature.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the problems. Some NP-complete problems are in APX (can be approximated to some constant amount) and some are not. This shows that you cannot in general assume the existence of a transformation such as the one you mention; this is spelled out [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/18937/on-apx-problems/18939#18939).

A concept somewhat similar to what you mention is [*APX-hardness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APX). First, some definitions. APX, as mentioned, is the class of problems approximable to some constant in polytime. PTAS is the class of problems which can be approximated arbitrarily well in polytime. A problem is APX-hard if there is a "PTAS reduction" (approximation-preserving reduction) from every problem in APX to that problem. One problem which is APX-hard is MAX-SAT.

A related definition is [MaxSNP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAX-SNP). This is a class of graph problems with the following property: there is a PTAS reduction from every problem in APX to some problem in MaxSNP.